# Tastypie relationship fields on obj_get_list

Tags: tastypie

I have a very standard user/group many to many relationship with the following simplified definition:

```
class GroupResource(ModelResource):
    users = fields.ToManyField(UserResource, 'group_set')

class Meta:
    cache = SimpleCache()
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    resource_name = "hr/group"
```

When I get a list groups it returns the group along with the list of uris of users connected to the group. However, our production system is starting to get quite large and a group can have hundreds of users in it. It is becoming painstakingly slow to return a list of groups, since each group also returns with it a list of users connected to that group.

Is there a way to exclude the linked users only for obj_get_list, but include the users when viewing the group instance? Or is there another solution to this problem that will fit better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify a `callable` as `use_in` argument to `fields.ToManyField` which returns `False` if current request corresponds to get_list end point.

### Example code

```
def is_not_group_get_list_end_point(bundle):
    # TODO: use dynamically generated path here.
    if bundle.request.get_full_path() == '/api/v1/hr/group/':
        return False
    return True


class GroupResource(ModelResource):
    users = fields.ToManyField(UserResource, 'group_set',
                              use_in=is_not_group_get_list_end_point)

    class Meta:
        cache = SimpleCache()
        queryset = Group.objects.all()
        resource_name = "hr/group"
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm on version 9.11, so will have to upgrade.